# Object not set to an instance in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i have this code:

```
Dim txt = CType(GridView1.FindControl("cnt_content"), TextBox)
        txt.Attributes.Add("style", "word-wrap:break-word;")
```

i'm always getting that txt is an object not set to an instance of an object
that's my asp code:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="cnt_id">
    <Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Content">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                         <asp:TextBox ID="cnt_content" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("cnt_content") %>' />
                </EditItemTemplate> 
                <ItemTemplate> 
                    <asp:Label ID="lblcnt_content" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("cnt_content") %>'></asp:Label> 
                </ItemTemplate> 
                <ItemStyle wrap="true" Width="400px" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

any help?

Comment: Most likely, I would guess that your control `cnt_content` does not exist or isn't a `TextBox`...

Comment: well it exist and it's a textbox

Comment: Well, it doesn't exist where you think it does. Extract the call to `GridView1.FindControl("cnt_content")` to a local variable and examine it in the debugger - my guess is it will be returning `null`.

Comment: Where is the `Dim txt = ...` code running at?  Also, you have 2 controls with the same name.  Although allowed in this context that is usually a very bad idea.

Comment: It is not a good idea to name controls the same thing, you have a text box and label with the same name of `cnt_content`. I realize they are in different templates and should never exist at the same time, but it is confusing for anyone else looking at your code.

Comment: it's running on the page load... okey okey i changed the names but i'm still facing the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you are trying to find this control in the `RowDataBound` event, like this:

```
Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)

End Sub
```

You need to only check for this control on data rows, not header or footer rows, as the control will not exist in those other types of rows, try this:

```
Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    ' Only check in data rows, ignore header and footer rows
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        ' Determine if you are in edit mode or not
        If GridView1.EditIndex = -1 Then
            ' Not in edit mode so look for label control defined in ItemTemplate of grid view
            ' Put logic here for label control
        Else
            ' In edit mode so look for textbox control defined in EditItemTemplate of grid view
            Dim txt = CType(GridView1.FindControl("cnt_content"), TextBox)
            txt.Attributes.Add("style", "word-wrap:break-word;")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Updated answer to account for which template (`ItemTemplate` or `EditItemTemplate`) of the grid view you are using.

Comment: @JocelyneElKhoury - have you tried the code that branches based on whether you are in edit mode or not?

Comment: Glad you accepted the answer, feel free to up-vote the answer as well. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It means that `GridView1.FindControl("cnt_content")` is returning null, which likely means that `GridView` does not *directly* contain a control called `"cnt_content"`.

Comment: it's a textbox in a row in the grid